# Creating an array of swifty-json strings

Tags: swift, swifty-json

I asked another question similar to this one but I will try rewording it in order to make it clear exactly what it is I am trying to do. I currently have a JSON file that breaks down like so: There is a top level object, from that object there is an array of objects, each containing strings and ints. I want to get certain string values from these objects into an array that I can use to display in a UITableView and the only methods I see posted everywhere use this .append function, which is great when you are only checking the array to append one time maybe a few times a week but I would like the array to display the most current version every time the func is called.

So far I have tried many different methods in order to cast the Name string that is contained within each of the objects into an array by .appending an array in swift that I called NameList. Doing it this way causes the program to stall while it appends each of the names into the array. My last question got the recommendation of doing a plist instead but I think because I wasn't clear on exactly what problem I have been having was. So to sum it up again I just want to cast all the string values into an array that can be called by the tableview. Is there anyway to do this without appending the array each time and just have the strings from the json to go directly to the tableview? My current code is:

```
func updateArr() {        
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("CardList", ofType: "json")
    let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)
    let json = JSON(data: jsonData!)
    for (key, subJson) in json["array"] {
        if let Name = subJson["Name"].string {
            if let Class = subJson["Class"].number {
                if Class == Int(1) {
            cardNameList.append(Name)
            println(cardNameList)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for not continuing to answer the comments in the other post.
Again I recommend to use a property list file.

It seems that you have an array of dictionaries with two keys `name` and `Class`,
so the plist structure could look like

```
<dict>
    <key>array</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>Alpha</string>
            <key>Class</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>Beta</string>
            <key>Class</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
        </dict>
    <array>
</dict>
```

then you can easily filter and map the data with

```
if let cardArray = plistDict["array"] {
  let names = cardArray.filter {$0["Class"] == 1} .map {$0["name"]! }
}
```

plistDict is the deserialized content of the plist file

Comment: My only concern with converting to a plist is that I had also planned on using this database in android as well and update both simultaneously in the same language. From my understanding json is much easier to work with in android as far as simple databases are concerned.

Comment: I was under the impression, that the highest priority is speed. I guess this is one of the fastest ways to filter and map a large amount of data. And with ObjC or Swift it's very easy to convert JSON to plist and vice versa.

Comment: I was trying my hardest to avoid having to redo my whole database but you pretty much convinced me that I should. With a plist am I still going to have to parse the data into an array for displaying on a Tableview or will I be able to do it with only the mapped strings?

Comment: what information do you want to display (how many properties)? So far we have only `name` and `Class`

Comment: Class wont be displayed it is just a sort tool to determine which names might be stored. There are also 3 other ints and a description string which will be displayed.

Comment: if the other properties are on the same level as `name` and `Class` it's very easy for example `map { ["name" : $0["name"] as! String, "description" : $0["description"] as! String, "index" : $0["index"] as! Int]  }`. If the properties are on other levels it's still possible but it's more – and slower –code. The smartest way is to map the dictionary to a custom class with designated initializer. The benefit of a custom class is no more type casting in the table view datasource method

Comment: Yea that makes sense to me. I guess I will spend my hours starting Monday reconverting my data over to plist. All the properties are on the same lever as name and class. I would imagine lets say I only wanted all the Classes that = 10 that it would be easy enough to only allow those onto the tableview and all the information that comes from their parent objects?

Comment: yes, just filter `$0["Class"] == 10` and create the dictionary in the `map` closure as described above

Comment: Then I guess this is the right I will try tomorrow or monday! Thank you for your very informative lesson on plist!!!

Comment: Do you know any good applications for mac that actually help create plist files easily?

Comment: usually I'm doing that in code. You may use only (NS)Array, (NS)Dictionary, (NS)String, NSNumber (and the Swift structs representing numbers), NSData and NSDate. Just write the enclosing array or dictionary to disk and you get a property list. However I'd prefer the class `NSPropertyListSerialization` to serialize the data

Comment: What type of file do you actually build the plist in? Do you build it in a swift class or a cocoa touch class?

Comment: I prefer Swift because the literals and numeric types are easier to use (much less @ characters)

Comment: Alright I will give it a try this my first time actually creating a database from scratch without using a prebuilt application dedicated on this. I guess it will be a good learning tool for me to really focus on my coding making sure I am typing everything out correctly! Above I notice the plist is already in format is there anyway I can get an example of how to structure the plist using swift?

Comment: property list is XML. The Cocoa representation is just an array or dictionary root object including other arrays and dictionaries. You don't have to care of the file signature header or of tags. Just create the dictionary/array structure and write the file to disk. Cocoa does the rest. By the way  I guess there are many examples here on stack overflow

Comment: Not sure if you are still around for this vadian but one final question how do you actually get to read the plist file to get to the starting section of code I tried the few examples I've seen but they seem outdated? Any advice on that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: simplest  solution ` let plistDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: "/path") as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>` or the NSArray equivalent, both methods deserialize the property list into the appropriate collection types. If you want finer control – for example read and write binary data rather than plain text – use NSPropertyListSerialization. In the documentation guides  `Archives and Serializations Programming Guide` and `Property List Programming Guide` are examples

Comment: I take it back there is one more question as I can't seem to find anything to reference this I have certain parts of the text that I was going to have bold when displayed in the tableview and i was using <b>""</b> as my reference to do so with the json file. I have seen a few posts on it but all are very old as well. Is there anyway to do this with a .plist file?

Comment: I doubt that a text field in a table view cell can handle those attribute tags automatically. So you have to strip and convert it to string attributes via NSAttributedString anyway. If you are concerned about the `<` and `>' characters, the plist serialization will escape them respectively

Comment: Alright thanks! I wasn't worried about the <> I just used that more as a reference to break the code for what I wanted specifically. I know there was a github that used ** ** at one point but I am not sure that it is still up to date and good to use for ios.

Comment: The one error I am getting currently is the .filter function. I finally starting working again on this part of the project and it says that I don't have a member named .filter?

Answer (score 1):

Casting values from json object to defined values can be like that

```
if let Name:String = subJson["Name"] as! String {
       if let Class:Number = subJson["Class"] as! Number {

       }
}
```

Comment: And doing it this way will allow it to go easily into an array without having to append array each time? Basically just looking to get ["Name"] in a tableview.